# Remove a record where record is not like parameter - Lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

I am using a lambda expression to check a parameter against a list of agencies then removing all agencies where the parameter isn't a partial match or full match. For example, if I have list of Ron's Accounting, Bill's You Can Count on me Automotive, and Julies Cooking supplies, the lambda expression should remove Julies Cooking Supplies when the parameter "count" is passed through. How do I accomplish this using a lambda expression? Here is what I have been trying.

```
copyAgencies.RemoveAll(a => a.AgencyName != a.AgencyName.Contains(param));
```

I think it should be like the wildcard in sql, or like.

Pseudo code, if param is not LIKE AgencyName, then remove.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all elements where the `AgencyName` doesn't contain your `param` value:

```
copyAgencies.RemoveAll(a => !a.AgencyName.ToLower().Contains(param.ToLower()));
```

Comment: I just ran this through and it removes everything. The param I am using is "count" which should return the agency Bill's You Can Count on me Automotive.

Comment: just ran it, I have all the records, then after this I have none

Comment: I am not sure how it should remove everything either, I just tried it and Ron's Accounting is what I get in the result, once toLower is used, the result is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`string.Contains` is case-senstive. Try:

```
copyAgencies.RemoveAll(n => -1 == n.IndexOf(param, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

when `param` is set to `"count"`, `copyAgenciesshould` then have:

```
{"Ron's Accounting" ,"Bill's You Can Count on me Automotive"}
```